# compare a dataframe column with 2D list python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe `data` :

```
Stretch
SB
NB
...
WB
```

where the row will have `Nan`. And I have 2D list :

```
[['SB', someFloatvalue, someFloatvalue], ['SB', someFloatvalue, someFloatvalue], ['NB', someFloatvalue, someFloatvalue]]

[['NB', someFloatvalue, someFloatvalue], ['SB', someFloatvalue, someFloatvalue], ['NB', someFloatvalue, someFloatvalue]]
```

For every 2D list above is tied to each row in `Stretch`. I want to remove all list which is not the same as `Strecth` value. In the end, the expected outcome is :

```
[['SB', someFloatvalue, someFloatvalue], ['SB', someFloatvalue, someFloatvalue]]

[['NB', someFloatvalue, someFloatvalue], ['NB', someFloatvalue, someFloatvalue]]
```

Explanation:
First row of `Stretch` is `SB`. Hence the respective 2D list should only list with `SB` in it. And so on...
In case of `Nan` in `Stretch`, just display the list the way it is.

My thought is to convert `Stretch` to `tuple` as i thought the position is important. It didn't work out.. I don't know how to map them..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) in *list-comprehension*:

```
out = [[l for l in sub_data if l[0] == key or str(key) == "nan" ] for sub_data, key in zip(data, df.Stretch)]
```

Or in usual for loop with:

```
out_1 = []
for sub_data, key in zip(data, df.Stretch):
    sub = []
    for l in sub_data:
        if l[0] == key or str(key) == "nan":
            sub.append(l)
    if len(sub) > 0: out_1.append(sub)
```

---

Full code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Stretch": ["SB", "NB", np.NaN]})

data = [[['SB', 123456, 123456], ['SB', 123456, 123456], ['NB', 123456, 123456]],
        [['NB', 123456, 123456], ['SB', 123456, 123456], ['NB', 123456, 123456]],
        [['NB', 123456, 123456], ['SB', 123456, 123456], ['NB', 123456, 123456]]]

# Usual for loop
out_1 = [[l for l in sub_data if l[0] == key or str(key) == "nan"] for sub_data, key in zip(data, df.Stretch)]
print(out_1)
# [[['SB', 123456, 123456], ['SB', 123456, 123456]],
#  [['NB', 123456, 123456], ['NB', 123456, 123456]],
#  [['NB', 123456, 123456], ['SB', 123456, 123456], ['NB', 123456, 123456]]]


out_2 = []
for sub_data, key in zip(data, df.Stretch):
    sub = []
    for l in sub_data:
        if l[0] == key or str(key) == "nan":
            sub.append(l)
    if len(sub) > 0: out_2.append(sub)

print(out_2)
# [[['SB', 123456, 123456], ['SB', 123456, 123456]],
#  [['NB', 123456, 123456], ['NB', 123456, 123456]],
#  [['NB', 123456, 123456], ['SB', 123456, 123456], ['NB', 123456, 123456]]]

print(out_1 == out_2)
# True
```